# Python guess the word game bugs

Tags: python

I created a guess the word game and basically when you run it it will ask you to enter 3 words and you have 10 lives to try and guess it. But I have a some problems, the loop wont end and some sentences keep repeating and I don't know how to save the hidden so it will be saved for the next letter. If someone can help me I will be very thankful.

Here is the code:

```
mport re
import sys
import random

FirstWord = input("Enter your first word: ")
if not re.match("^[a-z]*$", FirstWord):
    print ("Sorry Only non capital letters are allowed.")
    sys.exit()
SecondWord = input("Enter your Second word: ")
if not re.match("^[a-z]*$", SecondWord):
    print ("Sorry Only letters are allowed.")
    sys.exit()
ThirdWord = input("Enter your Third word: ")
if not re.match("^[a-z]*$", ThirdWord):
    print ("Sorry Only letters are allowed.")
    sys.exit()

Words = [FirstWord,SecondWord,ThirdWord]

try:
    fh = open("/Users/naomi/Documents/Vocabulary.txt","a")
except IOError as e:
    print("File does not exist or error when opening")
    exit()
else:
    fh.write (FirstWord)
    fh.write (SecondWord)
    fh.write (ThirdWord)
    fh.close()

GeneratedWord = random.choice(Words)

hidden = '_ ' * len(GeneratedWord)
print ()
print ("Word: ",hidden)

count =10

while count >=1 :
    guess = input("Take a guess ")
    if len(guess) != 1:
        print ("Only one letter can be entered at a time!")
    elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
        print ("Only letters are excepted!")
    for letter in GeneratedWord:
        if letter in GeneratedWord:
            show = GeneratedWord.index(guess)
            unhidden = hidden[:show*2] + guess + hidden[show*2+1:]
            print ("Guess is correct!")
        else:
            count = count-1
            print ("Your guess was wrong")
    print()
    print(unhidden)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your second If statement, your counter is only getting decremented if the guess is wrong. I'm assuming you need your counter to decrement every time they make a guess, whether it's right or wrong.

Comment: The guess is going trough all the letters one by one decreasing the count by every 1 turn according to how many letters there are in the word chosen. I want every guess to take one count, not like 6 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line has a logical error

```
for letter in GeneratedWords:
    if letter in GeneratedWords:
```

Change it to:

```
for letter in GeneratedWords:
    if (guess == letter):
```

Or:

```
if (guess in GeneratedWords):
```